# jQuery extract a json substring in a very big string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got an ajax string respond like the following:

```
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index:  in C:\wamp\www\form.php on line <i>464</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0008</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>274560</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin-ajax.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8826</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38298888</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>do_action(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin-ajax.php<b>:</b>85</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8827</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38300392</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.call-user-func-array:{C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php:505}' target='_new'>call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php:505}</a>
        (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\plugin.php<b>:</b>505</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8827</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38300560</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Example_Post->ajax_Example_posting_form(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\plugin.php<b>:</b>505</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>5</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8827</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38301552</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Example_Post->Example_form_submitting(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\form.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Example-frontend-form.php<b>:</b>116</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\form.php on line <i>475</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0008</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>274560</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin-ajax.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8826</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38298888</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>do_action(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin-ajax.php<b>:</b>85</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8827</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38300392</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.call-user-func-array:{C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php:505}' target='_new'>call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php:505}</a>
        (  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\plugin.php<b>:</b>505</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8827</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38300560</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Example_Post->ajax_Example_posting_form(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Example\wp-includes\plugin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\plugin.php<b>:</b>505</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>5</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.8827</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>38301552</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Example_Post->Example_form_submitting(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\form.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Example-frontend-form.php<b>:</b>116</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"redirect_to":"false","show_message":true,"message":"<div class=\"notification alert-success\"><p>Post updated successfully<\/p><a href=\"#\" class=\"close-btn\">\u00d7<\/a><\/div><br \/>"}
```

But much bigger. I want to extract the json object (you can see it at the last lines, but it is not always at the bottom of the string) to use it in `$.parseJSON` jQuery method.

Can anyone help me to achieve that please?

Comment: Probably your best option is to build a Regular Expression to fit with the JSON you want to extract

Comment: That HTML code is telling you there are errors!

Comment: Sorry probably warnings actually. You should pay attention to them and resolve the underlying issues but if you turn off warnings in PHP then that should return a pure JSON response.

Comment: you should|must fix the errors in php part instead (I think is your wamp, so you have control of code)

Comment: Please see the accepted answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: I know that, there are so many php notices.

Comment: You can disable the notices. See the thread please.

Comment: I don't want to disable them. because I want to give this script to more than one person and I cant guarantee that they can disable the errors.

Comment: You can if you disable them per-page. That would be best in your instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to solve your issue. To get to the underlying cause (if you don't want to make sure your variables are actually set before using them), one of these two options are available:

--

Find your `php.ini` file and update your `error_reporting` setting as-follows:

```
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
```

[Answer by binfalse from this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/263167/disabling-php-deprecation-warnings-and-notices)

--

If you want to disable per-page then modify the PHP file you're accessing and include this line somewhere at the top inside of the `<?php ?>` tags (inside of your `C:\wamp\www\form.php` file):

```
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
```

[Accepted answer from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: If I used this code are the errors and notices logged to the error log?

Comment: @Engr.MTH I don't believe so but I would recommend checking yourself if you want to be certain.

Comment: Thank you so much your code did it great and solved everything, And yes the errors and notices logged to the error log.

Comment: @Engr.MTH I should have probably also mentioned that the first method sets which exceptions you would like to have reported and the second one sets which ones you don't want to have reported. Only E_NOTICE warnings will be forcefully suppressed using the second option. Fatal errors will still behave normally. Also, thanks for reporting back with specific logging behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to find anywhere in tags .

```
var regex = '^\{\".*?\"\}';
```

Comment: I would upvote this but there is a better solution which will take care of the underlying issue that the OP is attempting to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex: `/(\{\".*?:.*?\"\})/`
This will give you the json in a matched group.

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/cV7oK7/1

Use like so:

```
var regx = /(\{\".*?:.*?\"\})/g,
    match = "";
while (match = regex.exec(yourString) !== null) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(match[0]);
    //use the json
}
```